# How to capture particular string in file

Tags: bash, grep, glob

I want to find occurences of the string `Execution has sterted` from a set of files,
say the three files present in the directory `/home/abc/output/`.

For that, I'm currently using the following command:

```
grep "Execution has sterted" /home/abc/output/*
```

It outputs:

```
/home/abc/output/file1:line containing "Execution has sterted"

/home/abc/output/file1~:line containing "Execution has sterted"

/home/abc/output/file2:line containing "Execution has sterted"

/home/abc/output/file2~:line containing "Execution has sterted

/home/abc/output/file3:line containing "Execution has sterted"

/home/abc/output/file3~:line containing "Execution has sterted"
```

Even though 3 files are there, output consists of 6 lines, with the original path(s) and other path(s) ending with `~` as shown above.

I want it to show occurences of the original path(s), not the `~` ones.
How to achieve this?

Thanks All,

It works for me.

My Actual query is, through crown job perticular job will run and will genrates say 3 log files.Each log file will consists of statements out of  which I need to catpure 2 statements say grep "Execution has sterted" and "Execution completed successfully".
Once I get above two statements then only I can conform job completed successfully.(because some time job got stuck at certain point)

how this can be done through scripting?
I should get message as job completed or job failed

Comment: What is the output of `ls`?  I'm inclined to think you copied your files at some point and these `~` files do actually exist.  There's no reason `grep` would write `/home/abc/output/file1~` unless such a file existed.

Answer (score 3):

The files ending with `~` are usually **backups** made by text editors when they save files.
The easiest solution is to **remove them first** by doing `rm /home/abc/output/*~`.

---

If you want to keep them, you can instead pass the `--exclude=` option to grep.
That'll make it exclude files matching the given glob pattern.

For example, in your case:

```
grep --exclude="*~" "Execution has sterted" /home/abc/output/*
```

Files matching `*~` will be excluded.
(don't forget to enclose the pattern in quotes so it gets passed directly to grep)

Comment: Hi, How to capture 2 strings from same log file. For ex my 1st string is "Job has started" and 2nd string is "Job completed successfully"

Comment: You'd have to run two separate grep commands, or use an search expression like `(Job has started)|(Job completed successfully)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
grep --exclude="*~" "search string" /path/*
```

Comment: Hi, How to capture 2 strings from same log file. For ex my 1st string is "Job has started" and 2nd string is "Job completed successfully"

Answer (score 1):

To prevent `grep` from seeing the backup files in the first place (removing the need for `--exclude`), use a pattern that omits them.

```
grep "Execution has sterted" /home/abc/output/*[!~]
```

`*[^~]` should also work; POSIX (for reasons I am unaware of) replaces the `^` used in regular expressions as the negation character, but `bash` supports both.

Comment: Hi Experts, how this can be achived in windows, i.e. capturing perticulare string say "job completed successfully"in text files(say 4) stored in perticular path say c:\CBA\TEST